# VS Code font size remains same even after updating the fontSize in settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code installed on Ubuntu 18.04.

The font size are very small and I want to increase it.

So I changed in Preferences -> Settings (both in user and workspace settings).

But still the size of the font is same.

[image: VS Code font Size settings]

Below is the `settings.json` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and entered `settings`:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 20,
    "editor.fontWeight": "200",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue"
}
```

Any suggestions why the font size remains same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the environment font size, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. This will change the default value of `"window.zoomLevel"` in settings.